# NUnit Api запуск теста по имени

Tags: c#, .net, nunit

Не смог найти в документации возможность запуска теста по имени. Пробовал запускать, используя TestFilter, но желаемого результат не получил. Возможно кто-то сталкивался, буду очень благодарен, спасибо!

Comment: [Visual Studio Test Adapter](https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/Visual-Studio-Test-Adapter)

Comment: увы, но нет... Нужно наподобие nunit-console реализовать, с возможностью запускать определенные тесты по названию.

Comment: [NUnit Console and Engine](https://github.com/nunit/nunit-console/releases/tag/3.8). Скачиваете, находите в архиве `nunit-console`

Comment: спасибо большое, но я ожидаю более конструктивного ответа.

Comment: Извините, как говорится, чем богаты...

Comment: как по мне, то я бы использовал teamcity, но задача состоит не в этом. На данном этапе я ковыряю исходники nunit engine и console, думал если кто сталкивался, то подскажет, дабы сэкономить время.

Answer (score 0):

Для запуска определенного теста необходимо использовать команду --where или метод "SelectWhere" класса TestFilterBuilder.

Comment: Там же есть более подходящий параметр `--test`.

Comment: Синтаксис подскажите, пробовал --test=testName работать отказывалось.

Comment: По идее правильно. Как именно отказывался работать? И какую версию NUnit'а используете?

Comment: В значении фильтра было наименование теста (<filter>...</filter>), но отображало количество тестов - 0, успешных - 0, и тд и тп.

Comment: Я сейчас обратил внимание, что в документации указано, что эта опция оставлена для обратной совместимости и что рекомендуют использовать как раз `--where`. Возможно в какой-то версии `--test` уже и перестал работать...

Comment: Можете пометить свой ответ как верный, кстати.